# Framework or library for creating user based rating systems such as in Digg, Reddit etc?

Tags: open-source, rating, voting

Looking for a good client side library using which I can create a reddit vote up / down, commenting, etc system?

The more mature the framework the better as this will go on a production site immediately.

Comment: Why do are you asking about client side rather than server side? What exactly do you want the client to be able to do?

Answer (score 3):

[Reditt](http://www.reddit.com/) is [open source](http://blog.reddit.com/2008/06/reddit-goes-open-source.html). Why don't you take a look?